# How can i remotely access my ubuntu server using openssh server?

Tags: ubuntu-server

I don't know how to remotely access to a virtual machine running a ubuntu server which has openssh server. Is there anyone can guide that if i want to access this virtual machine from anywhere, what should i do step by step ? Thanks :)

Comment: We can't answer this unless you give us a _lot_ more information about your setup. What is the host OS? Is your LAN accessible from the internet? Is the virtual machine accessible from your LAN?

Comment: my host os is ubuntu 12.10 and my lan is accessible from the internet, i set up virtual machine using NAT networking. Is there any info necessary ?

Comment: How do you want to access the virtual machine? `ssh`, `ftp`, `http`?

Comment: As i mentioned in question name, i think saying using openssh server means that i want to access by ssh.

Comment: Yes, so it does. I guess I should have read the title, sorry :)

Comment: Have you considered using bridging networking for the vm instead of NAT? I think this is better and easier for the vm you want to access from other machines (servers for example) as with bridging they are part of the same subnet as the other machines.

Comment: yes, i did but i want to do both NAT and bridged networking by setting up two seperate virtual machine and see how different they are.

Comment: Ah nice, nothing better than testing! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how is your network configured, where is your remote server (same LAN, different LAN or internet for example) but I will try to give you the info related to ssh considering the network part is ok so you can ping your server from your machine. If this is not the case, you have 1st to figure out how to solve the networking problem before using ssh.

If your local machine is linux, you only need to issue:

```
ssh user@remote-machine
```

where user is the user you created on your remote server (if you just installed it and installed openssh-server without configuring it, this user will be allowed to ssh in the server).

and remote-machine is whatever you use to ping the machine (ip, hostname or url).

If your local machine is windows, install putty ([putty site](http://www.putty.org/) and configure user and remote-machine in the config.

Mainly if the remote machine is accessible from internet, this default config is not secure and you should configure `/etc/ssh/ssd_config` on your server to restrict password use, replacing with ssh keys at least. You can see how to configure ssh server better in [ubuntu server help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH)

EDIT:

Just saw in your comments your vm is behind NAT so to reach it you will need to forward port 22 to it on the router.

Comment: In advanced settings of vm, there is an option "port forwarding", i clicked, then appeared a table contain rows named Name, Protocol, Host IP, Host Port, Guest Ip and Guest Port respectively. It was automatically entered Rule 1 for Name row and TCP for Protocol row. What should i do ? Do you mean i should enter 22 for Guest Port row ?

Comment: Not sure what virtual machine software you are using but I think entering port 22 should be at least part of the solution.

Comment: Cannot edit previous comment anymore but this way, you will have to access your virtual machine using your vm host as remote-machine and it will do the port forward to the ssh server I think. To access from internet, you will also need to configure your external router to send port 22 to the virtual machine host (if it is not the same machine)

Comment: I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox. Inside  same computer, there is a host os (ubuntu) and a virtual machine running ubuntu server.

Comment: I left same name and protocol rows and wrote my ip for Host IP, 8080 for Host Port, ip of server for Guest Ip and 22 for Guest Port. Then from a different machine, i wrote username@ipofserver but it returned an error "No route to Host". What should i do ?

Comment: host port needs to be 22 and you should use your machine (vm host) or ip instead of @ipofserver. But this way all ssh connections to your machine will go to the vm server. This is why I don't like NAT networking for vm that need to be accessed from other machines.

Comment: Another way is to use your main router to route to the subnet of the vm server and avoid port forwarding totally.

Comment: ok i changed host port from 8080 to 22, what about guest port now ? what should i write for that ?

Comment: Guest port is 22 too so you forward all port 22 requests on your machine to port 22 of this vm server.

Comment: I changed, then tried to connect from a different computer again, this time i got this error : ssh: connect to host host_ip port 22: Connection refused

Comment: And when i checked on server by ping google.com , it returns unknown host google.com . I am bored and give a break, thank you for interest, i developed myself really thank you :)

Comment: Connection refused means that it reached something and you can find info on why refused in `/var/log/auth.log`. Anyways, try the bridged networking for relax, it is a lot easier as the machine will behave like other normal machines in the LAN. Using NAT networking means working with multiple subnets and networking part is a lot more complicated if you want to access the machines ;)